# Goodness of fit in TAChart Fit Series

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus, delphi

Is there any property to get an estimate for the goodness of fit in TAChart's Fit Series? I well understand that R<sup>2</sup> doesn't make sense for nonlinear regression; However, information like a p value or even Akaike's information criterion would be useful.

Alternatively, is this information provided by the ipfpol procedure from numlib? Unfortunately, FPC's numlib is nearly undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: TAChart is not a statistical package, the TFitSeries provides only very basic fitting. Nevertheless, a goodness-of-fit property (read-only) has been added in Laz 1.6. It calculates the R<sup>2</sup> as a simple measure of fit quality. However, there is also an event OnCalcGoodnessOfFit where you an plug in your own, more advanced calculation method; the event gives access to all data points used for fitting.